# Can't find an element by its xpath (slenium in python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Here's the full code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

words = list()                                          #initialize a words list
with open("sorted_words_list.txt", 'r') as data_set:    #opens the .txt file
    for line in data_set:                               #loops through every line in the .txt file
        words.append(line.strip('\n'))                  #removes the '\n' from the line and appends it to the word list

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'    #identifies the path for the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)                     #creates the driver
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

driver.get('https://jklm.fun/KNVC')                 #opens the web page
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

name_box = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//INPUT[@class='styled nickname']")  #finds the box to input the name
name_box.clear()                                                                        #removes whatever name is in the box
name_box.send_keys("SasuX")                                                             #inputs the name SasuX in the box
name_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)                                                         #enters the values (enters the game room)

driver.implicitly_wait(1)

syllable = ''

while True:
    try:
        syllable = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//DIV[@class='syllable']").text
        print(syllable)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    time.sleep(1)
```

I was trying to find the text contained in a div with its xpath, but i get a "Unable to locate element" error.

The problem it's not the fact that the page has to load, and this is because I'm running an infinite loop that keeps checking.

I think the problem might be the fact that I wrote the relative xpath by myself, and this is because the chrome inspection tool won't let me copy the relative xpath, but only the absolute xpath. I tryed using the absolute xpath, but it's not working.

I would be glad is someone could help me.

**EDIT:**

I had to change the code a little bit, so that I could show the full error.

Here's the modified code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

words = list()                                          #initialize a words list
with open("sorted_words_list.txt", 'r') as data_set:    #opens the .txt file
    for line in data_set:                               #loops through every line in the .txt file
        words.append(line.strip('\n'))                  #removes the '\n' from the line and appends it to the word list

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'    #identifies the path for the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)                     #creates the driver
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

driver.get('https://jklm.fun/VWMS')                 #opens the web page
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

name_box = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//INPUT[@class='styled nickname']")  #finds the box to input the name
name_box.clear()                                                                        #removes whatever name is in the box
name_box.send_keys("SasuX")                                                             #inputs the name SasuX in the box
name_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)                                                         #enters the values (enters the game room)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

syllable = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//DIV[@class='syllable']")
print(syllable.text)
```

And here's the full error I'm getting in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Samuel\code\bots\JKLM_bot_py\main.py", line 27, in <module>
    syllable = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//DIV[@class='syllable']")
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1251, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//DIV[@class='syllable']"}
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.115)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00A2D953+2414931]
        Ordinal0 [0x009BF5E1+1963489]
        Ordinal0 [0x008AC6B8+837304]
        Ordinal0 [0x008D9500+1021184]
        Ordinal0 [0x008D979B+1021851]
        Ordinal0 [0x00906502+1205506]
        Ordinal0 [0x008F44E4+1131748]
        Ordinal0 [0x00904812+1198098]
        Ordinal0 [0x008F42B6+1131190]
        Ordinal0 [0x008CE860+976992]
        Ordinal0 [0x008CF756+980822]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00C9CC62+2510274]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00C8F760+2455744]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00ABEABA+551962]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00ABD916+547446]
        Ordinal0 [0x009C5F3B+1990459]
        Ordinal0 [0x009CA898+2009240]
        Ordinal0 [0x009CA985+2009477]
        Ordinal0 [0x009D3AD1+2046673]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x760E6739+25]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77128FEF+1215]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77128FBD+1165]
```

Comment: Have you made sure in the dev tools that the xpath points to the right location?

Comment: Yes, if I input the xpath in the dev tools I can see the correct div being higlighted

Comment: I just edited the post. I had to change the code a little bit, and I added everything you asked for. Hopefully you'll be able to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. The problem is that I was trying to find an element that was inside an iframe. So I just had to add a part of code that switches to the iframe.

```
iframe = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//iframe[@src='https://falcon.jklm.fun/games/bombparty']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```